# Concatenar linhas com o mesmo codigo

Tags: postgresql, query, concatenação-de-string

Ao executar a query

```
select * from ivr_interacao,ivr_business where ivr_interacao.codigo = ivr_business.idvisita and ivr_business.campanha = 5 order by start_time asc
```

tenho a seguinte resposta:

```
CHAMADO ID VISITA   NOME    TELEFONE        PERCURSO    DATA
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111                   27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111                   27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111                   27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111       PLAYDATA    27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111       PLAYPERIODO 27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111       MENU        27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111       MENU        27/06/2018 11:03
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111                   27/06/2018 11:04
```

Entretanto queria que ficasse neste formato:

```
CHAMADO ID VISITA   NOME    TELEFONE        PERCURSO                              DATA
7193751 799445  MARIA BATISTA   11111 '','',PLAYDATA,PLAYPERIODO,MENU,MENU,'' 27/06/2018 11:03
```

mas não estou sabendo concatenar, tentei utilizando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  codigo,
    nomecliente,acao,
COALESCE(
    (SELECT CAST(nomecliente AS VARCHAR(30)) + ';' AS [text()]
     FROM ivr_interacao AS O
     WHERE O.codigo  = C.idvisita

     ORDER BY nomecliente
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS Produtos
FROM ivr_business AS C
GROUP BY codigo,nomecliente;
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: usa o string_agg, mas vai ter que agrupar pelas outras colunas, a data, não parece ser a mesma, logo vai precisar estar dentro de uma função `MIN` ou `MAX` por exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apenas se o banco for PostgreSQL**

MySQL podes usar **group_concat**

```
select ivr_interacao.CHAMADO, 
       ivr_interacao.ID, 
       ivr_interacao.VISITA,
       ivr_interacao.NOME,
       ivr_interacao.TELEFONE,
       array_to_string(array_agg(ivr_business.PERCURSO), ', ') as PERCURSO,
       min(ivr_business.DATA) as data
  from ivr_interacao, ivr_business
 where ivr_interacao.codigo = ivr_business.idvisita 
   and ivr_business.campanha = 5 
 group by ivr_interacao.CHAMADO, 
          ivr_interacao.ID, 
          ivr_interacao.VISITA,
          ivr_interacao.NOME,
          ivr_interacao.TELEFONE;
```

Estou apenas especulando o nome das tabelas, isso pode variar.

Comment: Coloquei o MIN na data pois pelo que vi elas divergem.

Comment: no caso eu dou select em dados de duas tabelas, neste formato não rolou, mesmo declarando as duas tabelas...

Comment: nos campos tu colocarás os prefixos de cada uma das tabelas em cada campo do select no where e no group by.

Comment: Opa, perfeito, funcionou!